# GraphQL where clause to accept a Json object?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, prisma-graphql

So I have the following working GQL:

```
mutation updateManySomething{
    updateManySomething(
        data: {
            dateTime: "2020-01-15T13:07:42-06:00"
            status: true
            updatedBy: "1234"
        }
        where: { id_in: ["1234", "1234" ] }
    ) {
        count
    }
}
```

However when I try and make it accept passed variables it craps out because there is no ID! defined because it's an array of IDs....

```
mutation updateManySomething(
    $id: ID!
    $dateTime: DateTime
    $status: Boolean
    $updatedBy: String!
    ) {
    updateManySomething(
    data: {
            dateTime: $dateTime
            status: $status
            updatedBy: $updatedBy
      }
  where: { id_in: [$id] }
    ) {
        count
    }
}
```

I have tried skipping the $id: ID! and creating a new variable $arrayOfIds: Json but that fails as well, anyone have any idea what I can do? The backend is prisma JS is running in React-Native.

Below image is the exact error from Apollo some slight variables names changed but it’s essentially the same query.

[image: error image]

Comment: When posting questions about an error, please make sure you're posting the full error message. This makes it easier to answer your question and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find your question. If you're using Apollo Client, the errors returned by the server can be parsed from the `error` object returned by your `useMutation` hook.

Comment: Added an image with the error.

Answer (score 1):

If the schema expects a List of IDs, then you should define your variable accordingly:

```
mutation updateManySomething(
  $ids: [ID!]!
  $dateTime: DateTime
  $status: Boolean
  $updatedBy: String!
) {
  updateManySomething(
    data: {
      dateTime: $dateTime
      status: $status
      updatedBy: $updatedBy
    }
    where: {
      id_in: $ids
    }
  ) {
  count
  }
}
```

Note: A non-null type can be used where a nullable type is expected, but not vice versa. That means you can use `[ID!]!` even if the argument's type is `[ID]`, `[ID!]` or `[ID]!`.